# Java: how to use Google's HashBiMap?

Tags: java, guava

Keys are a file and a word. The file gives all words inside the file. The word gives all files having the word. I am unsure of the domain and co-domain parts. I want K to be of the type `<String>` and V to be of type `<HashSet<FileObject>>`.

```
    public HashBiMap<K<String>,V<HashSet<FileObject>>> wordToFiles 
            = new HashBiMap<K<String>,V<HashSet<FileObject>>>();

    public HashBiMap<K<String>,V<HashSet<FileObject>>> fileToWords 
            = new HashBiMap<K<String>,V<HashSet<FileObject>>>();
```

[Google's HashBiMap.](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/class-use/HashBiMap.html)

Comment: So what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: @Thomas: the problem is that there is no public constructor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

change it to

```
public HashBiMap<String,HashSet<FileObject>> wordToFiles = HashBiMap.create ();
```

But still it looks very strange. I think you should use another collection. From `BiMap` documentation (`HashBiMap` impelements `BiMap`):

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a
>   map that preserves the uniqueness of
>   its values as well as that of its
>   keys. This constraint enables bimaps
>   to support an "inverse view", which is
>   another bimap containing the same
>   entries as this bimap but with
>   reversed keys and values.

I don't know the problem you want to solve but after looking at your code I can suggest to consider using Multimaps. From its docs:

> A collection similar to a Map, but
>   which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K,
>   V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap
>   contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.

For example, you can do something like this:

```
Multimap<String, FileObject> wordToFiles = HashMultimap.create();
wordToFiles.put("first", somefile);
wordToFiles.put("first", anotherfile);
for (FileObject file : wordToFiles.get("first"){
   doSomethingWithFile (file);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Add this dependency to your 'build.gradle'

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
```

import BiMap and HashBiMap

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;
```

Create a bimap

```
BiMap<String, String> myBiMap = HashBiMap.create();
```

Put some values

```
myBiMap.put("key", "value");
```

Get mapping value by key,

```
myBiMap.get("key");
```

Get mapping by value,

```
myBiMap.inverse().get("value");
```