# How to create a 2 way map in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I need a data structure to store string-int value pairs in an 1:1 relationship, and being able too look up from either way their counterpart.

I wrote a class with a Hashtable and a String array and stored the data 2 times and used the built in functions for lookup.

My question is that is there a nicer way to accomplish this? And by nicer I mean being efficient and not storing the data 2 times, and preferably without writing a ton of code either :P.

Comment: See this simple answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39329515/5466401

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Java have a HashMap with reverse lookup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670038/does-java-have-a-hashmap-with-reverse-lookup)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It seems like you may be looking for a bimap.

The Google Collections (now a part of [Guava](https://guava.dev/)) contains an [`BiMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface with a few implementations.

From the `BiMap` documentation:

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a
> map that preserves the uniqueness of
> its values as well as that of its
> keys. This constraint enables bimaps
> to support an "inverse view", which is
> another bimap containing the same
> entries as this bimap but with
> reversed keys and values.

The [`BiMap.inverse`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html#inverse--) method appears to return a `Map` with the values as the keys, and the keys as the values, so that `Map` can be used to call `get` on the value and retrieve a key.

In addition the `Map` returned by `inverse` is a view of the underlying data, so it does not have to make extra copies of the original data.

From the `BiMap.inverse` method documentation:

> Returns the inverse view of this
> bimap, which maps each of this bimap's
> values to its associated key. The two
> bimaps are backed by the same data;
> any changes to one will appear in the
> other.

Comment: Javadoc link in answer no longer works.  Substitute:

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Comment: Like an actual example of how to use that library would be nice. It is just an interface with tons of implementations.

Answer (score 35):

You can do a simple implementation like this. Please note that the data is not copied in this implementation. Only the references are ! I have added implementation for add and get. remove and other required method are left as exercise :)

```
public class TwoWayHashmap<K extends Object, V extends Object> {

  private Map<K,V> forward = new Hashtable<K, V>();
  private Map<V,K> backward = new Hashtable<V, K>();

  public synchronized void add(K key, V value) {
    forward.put(key, value);
    backward.put(value, key);
  }

  public synchronized V getForward(K key) {
    return forward.get(key);
  }

  public synchronized K getBackward(V key) {
    return backward.get(key);
  }
}
```

And ofcourse its applications responsibility to ensue even the 'values' are unique. Example usage:

```
TwoWayHashmap twmap = new TwoWayHashmap<String, String>();
twmap.add("aaa", "bbb");
twmap.add("xxx", "yyy");
System.out.println(twmap.getForward("xxx"));
System.out.println(twmap.getBackward("bbb"));
```

Comment: Would be an interesting approach in the absence of Guava's BiMap. However, I'd suggest that you have this class implement the Map interface.

Comment: If you need class with Map interface, you can replace getBackward method with Map<K, V> inverse(), that will return inverse map.

Comment: K extends Object hardly needed.

Answer (score 14):

Apache Commons also includes the [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/userguide.html) (Bi Directional Map).

> Defines a map that allows bidirectional lookup between key and values.
>
> This extended Map represents a mapping where a key may lookup a value
>   and a value may lookup a key with equal ease. This interface extends
>   Map and so may be used anywhere a map is required. The interface
>   provides an inverse map view, enabling full access to both directions
>   of the BidiMap.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has a [BiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) that does what you want.

Comment: yup that does it! I couldn't find anything by searching for "2 way map" :P it seems bidirectional map is the right term

Comment: Javadoc link in answer no longer works.  Substitute:

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Answer (score 4):

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/),

```
    HashBiMap<String, String> map = HashBiMap.create();

    map.put("name", "Sohail");
    map.put("country", "Pakistan");

    Log.d("tag", "name is " + map.get("name"));


    BiMap<String, String>invmap= map.inverse();

    Log.d("tag", "Pakistan is a " + invmap.get("Pakistan"));
```

read complete tutorial [here.](http://www.sohailaziz.com/2013/03/bimap-two-way-map-in-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

*definitely w/o writing a ton of code → in lambda*
from Your `Map<String,Integer> map` You get the inverted map by

```
Map<Integer,String> inverted = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap( s -> map.get( s ), s -> s ) );
```

Answer (score -4):

Create a hashmap that maps Object to Object - then you can use the same map to store String -> Integer and Integer -> String.

When you add a string/int pair just add it both ways to the same map.

Comment: This is not a very sensible implementation at all. You throw all the generic type safety out the window, and increase the complexity of all the operations carried out on the map by double-adding entries. There is no encapsulation of the mechanism by which you are implementing the bi-directional map.

Comment: @Tom - I wrote the answer in a hurry and assumed the implementer would be sensible enough to wrap the hashmap in a class that controlled access to it and did the casting to the required types.  I will try to be clearer on that point in future.

Comment: Another problem you could run into is storing A->B and B->C, which should be fine with the question but not with your answer.