# Mapping and reverse mapping

Tags: data-structures

Is there a data structure that can replace the following two maps:

```
Dictionary<TypeA, TypeB> map;

Dictionary<TypeB, TypeA> reverse_map;
```

so that I will always be able to get TypeB from TypaA, and TypeA from TypeB? My current solution requires adding key->value to map 1 and value->key to map 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called a 'Bidirectional Map' like Google's [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) which is part of Google Collections (java library).

A related SO thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430170/how-to-create-a-2-way-map-in-java/3430209#3430209). This thread has a simple TwoWayHashmap java implementation posted by me. This uses two Maps to simulate a two-way-map. Although the code is java specific, I think it would be easy to generalize this as a data structure.