# Convert an int to a letter value

Tags: java, hashmap, encoder, decoder

Out of interest I have been working on a very basic encoder/decoder program. Super simple encoding, a = 1, b = 2... and from there it prints out to the numbers : "1 2 3". I have that working:

```
    final Map<Character, Integer> map;
    final String str = "hello world";

    map = new HashMap<>();  
    before Java 7.
    map.put('a', 1);
    map.put('b', 2);
    map.put('c', 3);
    map.put('d', 4);
    map.put('e', 5);
    map.put('f', 6);
    map.put('g', 7);
    map.put('h', 8);
    map.put('i', 9);
    map.put('j', 10);
    map.put('k', 11);
    map.put('l', 12);
    map.put('m', 13);
    map.put('n', 14);
    map.put('o', 15);
    map.put('p', 16);
    map.put('q', 17);
    map.put('r', 18);
    map.put('s', 19);
    map.put('t', 20);
    map.put('u', 21);
    map.put('v', 22);
    map.put('w', 23);
    map.put('x', 24);
    map.put('y', 25);
    map.put('z', 26);

    for(final char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        final Integer val;

        val = map.get(c);

        if(val == null)
        {   
            //error
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(val + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Now I am working on a way to convert it back. I think I could do it with a reverse hashmap of sorts but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Hashmap: How to get key from value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a 2 way map in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430170/how-to-create-a-2-way-map-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `HashMap` for this data at all.  Take advantage of the fact that the character values for these letters are all consecutive numbers.  That is, `'a'` is `97`, `'b'` is `98`, ..., `'z'` is `122`.

You can map a letter character to a number by subtracting`96`.

```
val = c - 96;
```

You can map the number back to the letter by adding `96`, then casting it back to a `char`.

```
c = (char) (val + 96);
```

Comment: What if the OP chose different encoding? i.e. `a = somenumber, b = somenumber+10, c = somenumber - 4`, etc...

Comment: [+1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments#comment126091_277314), but I would replace `96` with something like `public static int ENCODING_FLOOR = 'a' - 1`.

Comment: @DonLarynx A more random mixing of mapping from letters to numbers would make this solution not work.  But in this question, they are in order.

Comment: @yshavit Nitpick: `'a' - 1`.

Comment: @rgettman Nitpick on your nitpick on my nitpick: your nitpick pointed out a correctness issue on my nitpick, and thus isn't actually a nitpick. ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29), you can check to see whether the value has a key pre-image and what key it is. In fact, there are two functions that help this cause:

> boolean containsValue(Object value)
>
> Returns true if this map maps one or more keys to the specified value. More formally, returns true if and only if this map contains at least one mapping to a value v such that (value==null ? v==null : value.equals(v)). This operation will probably require time linear in the map size for most implementations of the Map interface

[Second method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html#getKey%28java.lang.Object%29)

> K getKey(Object value)
>
> Gets the key that is currently mapped to the specified value.
>
> If the value is not contained in the map, null is returned.

Comment: He is asking to reverse encoding I mean to convert 123 to abc. Your answer is not true for this question

Comment: Okey, you have edited your answer and now it is right answer. I tried to remove down vote but for doing this you should edit your answer, system does not allow removing

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
Integer integerToFind = ...;
Character matchingKey = null;
for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals(integerToFind)) {
        matchingKey = entry.getKey();
        break;
    }
}
```

This assumes there is no keys with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I like rgettman's answer but if you ever want a non ordered code this way might work better.

This uses Guava's BiMap
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;


public class Encoder
{

    private BiMap<Character, Integer> mCodeMap = makeCodeMap();

    public String encode(String string) 
    {
        string = string.trim();
        if (string.length() <= 0) return "";

        final StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
        char c = string.charAt(0);
        results.append(mCodeMap.get(c));

        for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); ++i) {
            c = string.charAt(i);
            results.append(' ').append(mCodeMap.get(c));
        }

        return results.toString();
    }

    public String decode(String string)
    {
        string = string.trim();
        if (string.length() <= 0) return "";

        String[] nums = string.split(" ");

        final StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();

        final BiMap<Integer, Character>inverse = mCodeMap.inverse();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
            final int num = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
            results.append(inverse.get(num));
        }

        return results.toString();
    }

    private static BiMap<Character, Integer> makeCodeMap()
    {
        BiMap<Character, Integer> codeMap = HashBiMap.create();

        codeMap.put('a', 1);
        codeMap.put('b', 2);
        codeMap.put('c', 3);
        codeMap.put('d', 4);
        codeMap.put('e', 5);
        codeMap.put('f', 6);
        codeMap.put('g', 7);
        codeMap.put('h', 8);
        codeMap.put('i', 9);
        codeMap.put('j', 10);
        codeMap.put('k', 11);
        codeMap.put('l', 12);
        codeMap.put('m', 13);
        codeMap.put('n', 14);
        codeMap.put('o', 15);
        codeMap.put('p', 16);
        codeMap.put('q', 17);
        codeMap.put('r', 18);
        codeMap.put('s', 19);
        codeMap.put('t', 20);
        codeMap.put('u', 21);
        codeMap.put('v', 22);
        codeMap.put('w', 23);
        codeMap.put('x', 24);
        codeMap.put('y', 25);
        codeMap.put('z', 26);
        codeMap.put(' ', 27);

        return codeMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        final String inputString = "this is my test input string";

        System.out.println("String = " + inputString);

        Encoder encoder = new Encoder();

        final String encoded = encoder.encode(inputString);
        System.out.println("Encoded = " + encoded);

        final String decoded = encoder.decode(encoded);
        System.out.println("Decoded = " + decoded);

        System.out.println("Correct = " + inputString.equals(decoded));
    }

}
```