# Collection : Mapping The Objects

Tags: java, collections

Assume I have two `List`s, one for `Movie`s and another one for `Genre`s. I want to map one or more `Genre`s to one `Movie` and/or one or more `Movie`s to one `Genre`. How would I do that?

Comment: Map<genre,List<movie>> <-- like this

Comment: @nafas Perhaps you should have written your comment as an answer, with an explanation to future readers?

Comment: @Luke answers should be precise where comments can be clue,

Answer (score 0):

The Java [`Map`-interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is used to map objects to other objects. A `Map<Movie, List<Genre>>` assigns a `List` of `Genre`s to a single `Movie`, a `Map<Genre, List<Movie>>` would do it the other way around.

If you want a 2-way-map, [there is already a question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430170/how-to-create-a-2-way-map-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The collection you should be using is `Map<String, List<String>>`.

For mapping one or more genre to a movie, you should use:
`Map<movie, List<genre>>`

And for mapping one or more movie to a genre, you should use:
`Map<genre, List<movie>>`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose...something like that:

```
Movie f = new Movie("fight club"); // for example..
List<Genre> genres = ...; 
genres.add(new Genre("comic"));
genres.add(new Genre("horror"));

Map <Movie,List<Genre>> movieGenres = new HashMap<Movie,List<Genre>>();

movieGenres.add(f,genres);
```

Comment: ...and don't forget to override hash and equals on your classes!

Answer (score 0):

Using appropriate map implementation.

```
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
```

I suggest you to look at Guava multimap

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put("action", "rambo");
multimap.put("action", "terminator");
multimap.put("thriller", "rambo");

System.out.println(multimap.get("action"));
System.out.println(multimap.get("thriller"));
```

Comment: I have a hard time finding the connection from this answer to the question. Consider explaining a bit further what you mean