# How can I get a key from a value in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

I have a problem finding a key from a specific value.

I know the other way round to find a value from a key but not a key from a value.
I think I found quite a lot solutions but I don't really understand them, can you help me please ?

```
HashMap<Spielfeldposition, Integer> risikoregionen = new HashMap<Spielfeldposition, Integer>();
```

Comment: language ? Example of your HashMap ?

Comment: Java.
 
HashMap<Spielfeldposition, Integer> risikoregionen = new HashMap<Spielfeldposition, Integer>();

We want to find the key "Spielfeldposition" by checking the highest value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Hashmap: How to get key from value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value)

Answer (score 0):

For the Java Collections API, you will have to ensure the 1:1 relationship between keys and values at the time of inserting the value into the map.

Then you can use entrySet() to get the mappings. Then you can iterate the values and get the corresponding key.

**EDIT**

```
Iterator entries = myMap.entrySet().iterator();

while (entries.hasNext()) {

Entry thisEntry = (Entry) entries.next();
Object key;

if(yourvalue == thisEntry.getValue()){
key = thisEntry.getKey();

return key
// ...
}}
```

Comment: ok, can u give us an example pls?

Map<Spielfeldpositionen, Integer> risikoregionen= 
        for(Spielfeldposition key : map.keySet()) {
            int value = map.get(key);
        }

like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to get keys from values, maybe the data structure you need is a bidirectional map. Question #770254, "*[How to create a 2 way map in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3430170/770254)*", deals with that.