# How to have multimap functionality in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to have the functionality of [MultiMap](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwj5x56q2ezGAhVkKaYKHTKDALs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Freference%2Fmap%2Fmultimap%2F&ei=iXquVbnfKuTSmAWyhoLYCw&usg=AFQjCNHbTAgd7jouzXIC_FC3MDpeRi6ODA&sig2=frmQJOU4iPb4WO-JrhogHA&bvm=bv.98197061,d.dGY) in Java, providing the same functionality as that of cpp MultiMap so that I am able to have multiple keys with the same value. Multiple elements in the container can have equivalent keys. I thought this will work :

```
TreeMap<Key, TreeMap<Key, Value> >.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Guava has implementations of multimaps.

Comment: Apache Commons too. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html

Comment: Do you need multiple keys mapped with the same value and Multiple value mapped with same key?

Comment: @Razib : yeah, I want it both ways. And I cannot use guava and others. I need to have it in Java.

Comment: @rt56 guava *is* in Java. Or did you mean that you cannot use an external library?

Comment: @VivinPaliath Yeah, I cannot use an external library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want consistent semantics, you would have to roll your own. The easiest way to implement it would be to back it by a `Map<K, List<V>>`. This way you can map one key to multiple values.

However, there are some things you need to consider regarding semantics. For example, assume you have the following multimap:

```
a -> [1, 2, 3]
b -> [4, 5]
```

The size of the above will be reported as 2, but could be interpreted as 5 also, if you consider that the Map can be represented as so:

```
a -> 1
a -> 2
a -> 3
b -> 4
b -> 5
```

This has implications for the values that you return as well. It would make more sense to return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and not `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]`. This would also apply to the entry set; you may want to return pairs as displayed above.

Hence a possible implementation would be to implement `Map<K, V>` and use a backing `Map<K, List<V>>`. You would then have to implement the various methods while adhering to the multimap semantic.

If you don't care about the semantics but just want an ability to map a single key to multiple values, you can just use a `Map<K, List<V>>` directly and still get what you need.

Comment: But lets see a scenario where i want to have multiple keys for the same value. With this implementation, I have to search in all the values. Lets say, A maps to [1,2,3] and B maps to [2]. Now I want to know the keys which has 2 as values which should be A and B both.
In all, this will not work both ways.

Comment: @rt56 That's a bi-map, or in this case a bi-multimap, which is different from just a regular multimap. To get that to work you would have to maintain a backing from the value to the key as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Vivin Paliath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31545731/642706) is correct. I’ll add more information, and more code.

## `Map#computeIfAbsent`

To pair multiple values with one key, use collection as the value type. Often the collection is a `List` or `Set`. Or perhaps a `Map` for more complicated structures.

As an example, suppose we want to track which employees are going to be working on which days of the week.

We define `Employee` as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Employee( int empNum , String name ) { }
```

Make some sample data.

```java
Employee alice = new Employee( 1 , "Alice" );
Employee bob = new Employee( 2 , "Bob" );
Employee carol = new Employee( 3 , "Carol" );
```

Each employee maps to a set of day-of-week values. For day-of-week, we can use enum objects defined on [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html). So we need a `Map < Employee, Set < DayOfWeek > >`.

```
Map < Employee, Set < DayOfWeek > > workDaysForEachEmployee = new HashMap <>();
```

Suppose we want to assign Monday to Alice.

### In earlier Java

Here is the old way to make that assignment. We try to retrieve an existing collection value. We do a null-check to see if indeed there was an existing collection value. If so, we add to it, and put it back into map. If not, we instantiate a new collection, add to it, and put it into map.

```java
Set < DayOfWeek > assignedDays = workDaysForEachEmployee.get( alice );
if ( null == assignedDays )
{
    assignedDays = EnumSet.noneOf( DayOfWeek.class );
}
assignedDays.add( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
workDaysForEachEmployee.put( alice , assignedDays );
```

When run.

> workDaysForEachEmployee.toString() = {Employee[empNum=1, name=Alice]=[MONDAY]}

### In modern Java 8+

Modern Java brought [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), a compact way of passing code as an argument.

We can use lambdas and other new Java 8 functionality to reduce that code seen above to a single line.

We call [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)). In that call we pass a lambda. The lambda creates a collection in which to hold values. If the map already has an entry with our desired collection, the lambda is not executed. One way or another, that `computeIfAbsent` method returns a collection value, a `Set< DayOfWeek >` in our case.

- If the collection value exists (has already been mapped to a key), the value is returned. In our case, if the employee has already been put into the map with a set of days, that set is retrieved and returned.
- If the collection value does not exist, a new collection is instantiated and returned.

In either case, pre-existing or freshly instantiated, we end up with a set in which to add our `DayOfWeek` object for the `alice` key.

```java
workDaysForEachEmployee
        .computeIfAbsent( alice , ( x -> EnumSet.noneOf( DayOfWeek.class ) ) )  // Returns a `Set< DayOfWeek >`, either a retrieved existing set, or a fresh new set. 
        .add( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
```

> workDaysForEachEmployee.toString() = {Employee[empNum=1, name=Alice]=[MONDAY]}

In that code above we instantiate a new collection by calling `EnumSet.noneOf( DayOfWeek.class )`. The `EnumSet` class is an implementation of `Set` that is highly optimized for containing enum objects, using very little memory, and very fast to execute. If you were using another type, such as a `List` you might use `new ArrayList<>()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case [guava BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) is the best option. Since you don't want to use it then you may create own collection - [`TwoWayHashMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430170/how-to-create-a-2-way-map-in-java/3430209#3430209) something like this:

```
public class TwoWayHashmap<K extends Object, V extends Object> {

  private Map<K,V> forward = new Hashtable<K, V>();
  private Map<V,K> backward = new Hashtable<V, K>();

  public synchronized void add(K key, V value) {
    forward.put(key, value);
    backward.put(value, key);
  }

  public synchronized V getForward(K key) {
    return forward.get(key);
  }

  public synchronized K getBackward(V key) {
    return backward.get(key);
  }
}
```

Visit the [attached link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430170/how-to-create-a-2-way-map-in-java/3430209#3430209) for more details.

Comment: The OP said that he cannot use Guava.