# Fast look up of key by value without creating an inverse hashmap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

If I have a `HashMap<KEY, VALUE>` and I need fast look up of the key **by the value** is there any other approach besides creating a second `HashMap<VALUE, KEY>` that store the same data but using the value as the key?
Is there any approach/tick about this? If it makes a difference my interest is about `String` both as key and value
**Note:** I am on Java 7

**Update:**
I am not sure why the other question is a duplicate as I am asking a specific way on implementing this.
Unless the only/best way is a 2 way map I can't see why this is a duplicate

Comment: How *fast* ? But most certainly having two maps is the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a 2 way map in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430170/how-to-create-a-2-way-map-in-java)

Comment: @Dici: It should not be O(N). I was interested if there is an efficient way to avoid the duplicate copy of data

Comment: @Dici:The answers in the post you linked are about 2 maps. That part I already knew to implement

Comment: Keep in mind that you're not creating a duplicate copy of the data. You'd be creating duplicate references to the same data.

Comment: @voters: Please see my update and elaborate a bit

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, Guava makes things better than you do. I would trust them on that

Comment: "Unless the only/best way is a 2 way map I can't see why this is a duplicate" well, it is essentially the only way, so yes.  (And Guava's implementation is noticeably smarter than just having two maps.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, there isn't.

You need two maps. If you want to use O(1) time for both, that means two hashmaps.

If you're worried about space, don't worry so much: you're just storing duplicate pointers, and not two strings.

I.e., you're just storing

```
HashMap<String* k, String* v> normal;
HashMap<String* k, String* v> inverse;
```

rather than entire strings. (Although pointers kind of don't exist in Java.)