# Data Model for two-way mapping of text fragments and class instances

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

[image: GUI example]

---

I would like to introduce the GUI similar to the previous example.

- On the left side, there are a collection of **paragraphs** *(instances of the **Paragraph** class)* that contain a
  collection of **words** *(Strings)*. As you can see – in the text, there are **highlighted text fragments** *(green, orange, blue)*.
- The **text fragment** is subcollection of words from concrete **paragraph**.
- On the right side, there are a collection of **facts** *(instances of the **Fact** class)*.
- Each **fact** is associated with at least one **text fragment** (there may be more – e.g. Fact #2).

---

*Code fragments:*

```
public class Paragraph {
    private List<String> words;
    …
}

public class Fact {
    private String text;
    …
}
```

---

I wish that this will be an **interactive GUI** (user can click on the text fragment => e.g. corresponding fact will be pop-uped / user can click on the fact => e.g. only corresponding text fragments stay highlighted).

Due to this, it is necessary that each **text fragment** knows corresponding **fact** and vice versa.

**How to achieve the linkage between the text fragments and the corresponding fact in Java and what are appropriate data-structures?**

I mean the data model of this linkage, not the GUI implementation. I suppose the word count is much higher than the number of text fragments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783020/bidirectional-map

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, something like the bidirectional map I will need. Actually, I have problem with the proposal of datastructure for **text fragments**. How to handle this information? I thinking of special **class** for each String **word**, but the most part of words aren't part of some text fragment.

Comment: @user3437460 Yes, if you mean reference back to **fact** from concrete **text fragment**.

Comment: Can one paragraph relate to multiple facts?

Comment: @user3437460 Yes, but the relation is between the concrete **text fragment = group of words** (not whole paragraph) and the **fact**. One paragraph can contain multiple **text fragments.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 1 fact can have multiple paragraphs, but 1 paragraph can only belongs to 1 fact. I will implement the classes as something like:

```
class Fact{

    private ArrayList<ParagraphText> paraTexts;
    private String text;        
    //any other attributes

    public Fact(){
        //initialization..
    }

    public void addParaText(ParagraphText p){
        paraTexts.add(p);
        p.linkWithFact(this);  //remember which fact p belongs to
    }

    public void removeParaText(ParagraphText p){
        if(paraTexts.contains(p)){
            p.unlinkFact();
            paraTexts.remove(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever you add a paragraph's text to the fact, the paragraph's text itself remembers which fact it belongs to.

```
class ParagraphText{

    private int startPos;
    private int endPos;
    private Fact fact;
    //any other attributes

    public ParagraphText(int startPos, int endPos){
        this.startPos = startPos;
        this.endPos = endPos;
        //any other initializations
    }

    public void linkWithFact(Fact fact){
        this.fact = fact;
    }

    public void unlinkFact(){
        this.fact = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @David let me know whether it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I think that we have a different view of the **paragraph**. The **paragraph** in this context is only something like the wrapper of collection of **words**. The **fact** is not related to the entire **paragraph**, but is related only to the some words of paragraph. The *Fact #1* from my exmple is related to the **7. and 8. word** from **the first paragraph**. Sorry, maybe it is not clearly from my intro description.

Comment: @David I tried to use shorter names for readability. It does not mean that it is the entire paragraph, else I would not have included the start and end positions. I have edited the naming for clarity.