# BFS using Adjecency Matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

**Question to find Bfs path ,, i am able to code bfs path if the graph have vertices marked as 0,1,2,3,4,,like this 
But can't able to apply adjacency matrix how to solve bfs for graph like 5,10,15,20
attached images what i have coded**

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4E33.png)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bfs {
        public static void bfsTraversal(int[][] adjMatrix) {
           Queue<Integer> pendingVertices = new LinkedList<>();
           boolean[] visited = new boolean[adjMatrix.length];
           visited[0] = true;
           pendingVertices.add(0);

           while (!pendingVertices.isEmpty()) {
              int currentVertex = pendingVertices.poll();
              System.out.print(currentVertex + " ");
              for (int i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {
                  if (adjMatrix[currentVertex][i] == 1 && !visited[i]) {
                    pendingVertices.add(i);
                    visited[i] = true;
                  }
              }
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       int v = s.nextInt();
       int e = s.nextInt();
       int[][] adjMatrix = new int[v][v];
       for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
           int v1 = s.nextInt();
           int v2 = s.nextInt();
           adjMatrix[v1][v2] = 1;
           adjMatrix[v2][v1] = 1;
       }
       bfsTraversal(adjMatrix);
   }
}
```

[Click here for Question for bfs like vertices 0,1,2,3,4...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNwqb.jpg)

[Click here for ,How i want to solve this  for bfs like vertices 5,10,15,20...](https://i.postimg.cc/htBYJWfb/IMG-20200307-171224.jpg)

And i want to do the same for graph like this ,,can't get logic

**Solved by mapping the input with 0,1,2,3.... and maintained a reverseMap**

[**Click here to view the Solution**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCzYZ.png)

Comment: Pretend it's like 0,1,2,3..., and then just print `(currentVertex+1)*5` instead of `currentVertex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the range of the numbers, you can let the numbers 5, 10, 15 and 20 be the IDs of the nodes and store the indices of the nodes in a seperate array. Suppose the name of the array is IndexLookupArray, if you want to lookup the index of a node with ID x you can find it in IndexLookupArray[x]. And the rest of the code should be the same. If the range of the numbers is unknown or if it's too big to fit in an array, you can store the indices in a hash map for example and do the same thing.

You can write something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bfs {
        public static void bfsTraversal(int[][] adjMatrix) {
           Queue<Integer> pendingVertices = new LinkedList<>();
           boolean[] visited = new boolean[adjMatrix.length];
           visited[0] = true;
           pendingVertices.add(0);

           while (!pendingVertices.isEmpty()) {
              int currentVertex = pendingVertices.poll();
              System.out.print(currentVertex + " ");
              for (int i = 0; i < adjMatrix.length; i++) {
                  if (adjMatrix[currentVertex][i] == 1 && !visited[i]) {
                    pendingVertices.add(i);
                    visited[i] = true;
                  }
              }
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

         int idx = 0;
         int range = s.nextInt();
         int v = s.nextInt();
         int e = s.nextInt();

         int[] IndexLookupArray = new int[range + 1]; // range + 1 since IndexLookupArray[range] should be accessible.
         int[][] adjMatrix = new int[v][v];

         Arrays.fill(IndexLookupArray, 0, range + 1, -1);

         for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
           int v1 = s.nextInt();
           if (IndexLookupArray[v1] == -1)
           {
             IndexLookupArray[v1] = idx;
             idx++;
           }
           v1 = IndexLookupArray[v1];

           int v2 = s.nextInt();
           if (IndexLookupArray[v2] == -1)
           {
             IndexLookupArray[v2] = idx;
             idx++;
           }
           v2 = IndexLookupArray[v2];

           adjMatrix[v1][v2] = 1;
           adjMatrix[v2][v1] = 1;
       }
       bfsTraversal(adjMatrix);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i have maintained a map and reversemap 
map to put value ,,,
reversemap to find the key,which will be our desired path
https://codeshare.io/50XZMn

BUT I WANT TO USE BI-DIRECTIONAL MAP
How to use that

Comment: look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783020/bidirectional-map/