# Double keyset Map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I need a `Map<String,Integer>` to store a binding between a set o strings and ints, for example:

```
"one"   <-> 1
"two"   <-> 2
"three" <-> 3
```

and in particular I need to use both String values and int values as key to access this map. I mean: `get("one")` returns `1` and `get(1)` returns `"one"`.

What's the best way to achieve this? is there some Map implementation that can help me?

Comment: Guava BiMap should do the job: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap

Comment: Yes.. `BiMap` is the way to go

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574685/java-how-to-use-googles-hashbimap

Comment: @Marco13 Thank you, please write your answer so I can pick it up.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions like this. First websearch result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783020/bidirectional-map Upvote whatever you want to upvote, a link is not really an "answer" in the stackoverflow sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use two `HashMap`s and write a method to query one of the two depending on what input you are giving it (`String` or `int`) or use the Guava library's `HashBiMap`, which does something like that behind the scenes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could possible create an inverted map on demand. This wont support same value for two keys.

```
public class InvertableMap<K, V>  extends HashMap<K, V> {

    public  InvertableMap<V, K> getInvertedMap() {
        InvertableMap<V, K> outputMap = new InvertableMap<>();
        for (K k : keySet()) {
            V v = get(k);
            outputMap.put(v, k);
        }
        return outputMap;
    }
}
```